# Java Eclipse Properties View implementation of "Show advanced properties"

Tags: java, eclipse, view, properties

I have a `TreeViewer` with Object which I want to show information in the default `PropertiesView` in Eclipse.
I created an `AdapterFactory` which implements the `IAdapterFactory` Interface with the Override method:

```
@Override
public Object getAdapter(Object adaptableObject, Class adapterType)
{
    if(adapterType == IPropertySource.class && adaptableObject instanceof UATreeNode)
    {
        return new UATreeNodeAdapter((UATreeNode) adaptableObject);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then I created an adapter which implements the `IPropertySource` Interface with my own `PropertyDescriptors`, for example:

```
public static final String OBJECT_ID_ACCESSLEVEL = "Obj.accessLevel";
private static final String OBJECT_LABEL_ACCESSLEVEL = "AccessLevel";

protected PropertyDescriptor objectAccessLevelDescriptor = new PropertyDescriptor(OBJECT_ID_ACCESSLEVEL, OBJECT_LABEL_ACCESSLEVEL);

@Override
public IPropertyDescriptor[] getPropertyDescriptors()
{
    return new IPropertyDescriptor[] { objectAccessLevelDescriptor };
}

@Override
public Object getPropertyValue(Object id)
{
    if(id.equals(OBJECT_ID_ACCESSLEVEL))
        return uaTreeNode.getAccessLevel();
}
```

I got more of those `PropertyDescriptors` and now I want to show some of them only if the "Show Advanced Properties" menu button in the `PropertiesView` is activated.

So my question, is this possible to do, if so what do I have to implement to show my Properties only if "Show Advanced Properties" is activated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the `PropertyDescriptor.setFilterFlags` method to set the expert filter property:

```
PropertyDescriptor desc = ...

desc.setFilterFlags(new String [] {IPropertySheetEntry.FILTER_ID_EXPERT});
```